# Class Clipboard doesn't exist in the current context, but I add namespace "System.Windows" where this class is kept

Tags: c#

System.Windows is included in the project. I tried to rebuild project few times, but error appeared everytime. I can't understand why is so? This project is class library, which I want to use in main project.

[On the right side is list of dependencies of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVM8t.png)

[Line of code with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et5XZ.png)

[Project properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1G0hB.png)

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;

namespace AccountStorage.Core.Models
{
    public class PasswordGenerator
    {
        private string password;
        public string Password
        {
            get => password;
            set => password = value;
        }

        public uint CharactersAmount { get; set; }
        public bool AddCapitalLetters { get; set; }
        public bool AddNumbers { get; set; }
        public bool AddSigns { get; set; }

        private Random randomiser = new Random();
        public void Generate(object p)
        {
            StringBuilder availableCharactersCollector = new StringBuilder(95);
            availableCharactersCollector.Append("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
            if (AddCapitalLetters) availableCharactersCollector.Append("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
            if (AddNumbers) availableCharactersCollector.Append("0123456789");
            if (AddSigns) availableCharactersCollector.Append(@" !#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~""");

            string availableCharacters = availableCharactersCollector.ToString();
            string pw = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < CharactersAmount; i++)
            {
                pw += randomiser.Next(availableCharacters.Length);
            }
        }

        public void Copy() => Clipboard.SetText(Password);

        public void Reset() => Password = "";        
    }
}
```

Comment: If you [go to the documentation for System.Windows.Clipboard and try to set the version to .NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.clipboard?view=windowsdesktop-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0), you get redirected with the message "The requested page is not available for .NET 5. You have been redirected to the newest product version this page is available for." That tells me it's not there in .NET 5. It's either been dropped or moved to some other location.

Comment: The [Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.clipboard?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) class is in the namesape `System.Windows`, in the assembly PresentationCore.dll